# "Sign in as different user" in SharePoint 2013 is not working is redirecting to Page Not found

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

In my scenario i am having **publishing site** and  enabled the *sign in as different user* in **welcome.ascx**, when i click the *sign in as different user* in the application is  redirected to **PageNotFoundError.aspx**. Its not asking for the credential. Kindly help me to resolve this

Comment: How did you enabled the option?

Comment: My understanding was that the functionality was removed in SP2013 due to many bugs that it caused (first one I can think of is  clicking on an Office document will open up Office as the currently logged in Windows user, not the one currently signed into SharePoint). As said below, the only supported way is to use the RunAs functionality to spawn the browser process as another user

Comment: Keep in mind using http://siteurl/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true may not work in some browsers and ie10

Comment: am using IE edge and its worked yesterday but its not working now

Answer (score 3):

> There are several solutions to your problem as Microsoft has removed
>   the Sign in as different user link.
>
> 1. Start your browser as a different user
> 2. Use the _layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true page
> 3. Edit the Welcome.aspx to include the link again ([Sign in as Different User and SharePoint 2013](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/sign-in-as-different-user-and-sharepoint-2013/))
> 4. Use JavaScript as a Bookmarklet ([SharePoint 2013 – Sign in as Another User](http://corypeters.net/2012/10/sharepoint-2013-sign-in-as-another-user/))

Please check the below links for more options

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139527/sign-in-as-different-user-in-sharepoint-2013
2. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odabasi/2013/08/16/missing-sign-in-as-different-user-option-in-sharepoint-2013/
3. https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/sign-in-as-different-user-and-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: i have added the code for enabling sign in as different user while click on that it is not moving to  _layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true page instead of this its moved to PageNotfound page

Comment: even i have pasted this _layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true and run the browser it goes http://ctv8vzq9b2srv01:13/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx?requestUrl=http://ctv8vzq9b2srv01:13/_windows/default.aspx

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in the URL which you have formed, can you pls share the url.

Answer (score 0):

as workaround you could just run IE(or other browser) as different user before log into the site

Comment: I have worked in IE edge and tried in all browser too